# InvalidArgumentExcelption occur to rum unit test case in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I am working in Symfony 2 framework. When I run unit test case through putty I got following Fatal Error.

Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'The "symfony/app" directory does not exist.' in /vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Finder/Finder.php

This error occur suddenly. Earlier everything was working properly.

Can anyone suggest some solution?

Comment: I found solution from this link [Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222504/phpunit-failing-in-phpstorm-w-exit-code-255-in-symfony-2-project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs because your application `kernel` location is not the standard directory.

You have to manually set the `kernel_dir` of your test suites like follows :

```
<phpunit>
    <php>
        <server name="KERNEL_DIR>" value="/path/to/your/app/" />
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

See the [Functional Tests](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#functional-tests) chapter of Symfony documentation.